# flex : redirect from jsp page

Tags: java, apache-flex, jsp, redirect

i am calling a page.jsp from flex application using http, i am checking for authentication on jsp page.now if user is valid than he should redirect to page2.jsp, and if user is invalid user than he should redirect to page3.jsp, i want to redirect from jsp page not from mxml page.

how should i do this?

Comment: i know jsp method <jsp: forwrd/> but it is not wroking for this.see this link.... http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg09101.html

Answer (score 0):

Forget `page.jsp` and use a [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/page2.jsp` and does the following job in `doFilter()` method:

```
if (user is valid) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue request.
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("page3.jsp"); // Redirect to page3.jsp.
}
```

Then let your Flex app just call `page2.jsp`.